# Post the media object from view to controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have requirement of posting mediaStreamObj from View to Controller and store it in the SQL Server in VarBinary. Later the varBinary data is passed to a different application for streaming. In the current core the stream data is coming as null. please help me to pass the actual data in stream to save it in the database and used it in different app to stream

**Javascript Code**

```js
let startRecord = document.getElementById("startrecord");
let stopRecord = document.getElementById("stoprecord");
let liveVideo = document.getElementById("livevideo");

let constraintObj = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
};

navigator.mediaDevices
.getUserMedia(constraintObj)
        .then(function (mediaStreamObj) {
            liveVideo.srcObject = mediaStreamObj;
            liveVideo.play();

            let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
            let chunks = [];

            startRecord.addEventListener("click", ev => {
                mediaRecorder.start();
            });
            stopRecord.addEventListener("click", ev => {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
            });
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function (ev) {
                chunks.push(ev.data);
            }
            mediaRecorder.onstop = function () {                
                let blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type': 'video/mp4' });
                HttpPost(blob);
                chunks = [];
            }
        })
        .catch(function () {
            console.log("Error");
        })

function HttpPost(blob) {    
    let params = {
         VideoStream: blob,
         VideoType: 'video/mp4'
    };

    //var formData = new FormData()
    //formData.append('VideoStream', blob)
    //formData.append('VideoType', 'video/mp4')

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Load/",
        data: params,
        success: function (msg) {       
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });  
}
```

**MVC - C#**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public string Load(VideoModel video)
{
    return View();
}

public class VideoModel
{
    public string VideoType { get; set; }
    public Stream VideoStream { get; set; }
}
```

HTML

```html
<button id="startrecord" 
    class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg btn-block" >Record</button>
<button id="stoprecord" 
    class="btn btn-outline-info btn-lg btn-block" >Stop</button>

<video id="livevideo" controls></video>
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are having? Is the `Load` action getting hit from the UI? `mediaRecorder.onstop` getting triggered?

Comment: yeah, its getting hit but the values are coming as null.